# Angular2 data from dataset won't take number[] array

Tags: html, angular, typescript, charts, dataset

I have recently bee nworking on charts and I am using the chartmodel of ngprime (pie). I want to pass my number array as data in the ts file but it will not show anything. The array gets filled in in the OnInit method.

UPDATE:

The numbers get filled in but only after some time and when i resize the window. Is there a method for the chart to only show when everything is loaded? I tried putting the data in the oninit etc but nothing seems to help. The arrays get filled in.

Kind regards

```
       import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {InternshipAssignmentService} from '../services/internshipAssignment.service';
import {IInternshipModel} from '../models/internship.model';


@Component({
  selector: 'coordinator-chart',
  templateUrl: 'coordinatorChart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../../assets/css/in/style.css']
})

export class CoordinatorChartComponent implements OnInit{
// afstudeerrichtingen, technologieen
  dataAfst: any
  options: any;
  dataTech: any;
  internships: IInternshipModel[] = [];
  specialisations: string[] = [];//;
  specialisationsArray: number[] = [this.specialisations.length];

  constructor(private _service: InternshipAssignmentService) {
    this.dataAfst = {
      labels: this.specialisations,
      datasets: [
        {
          data: this.specialisationsArray,
          backgroundColor: [
            "#FF6384",
            "#36A2EB",
            "#FFCE56"
          ],
          hoverBackgroundColor: [
            "#FF6384",
            "#36A2EB",
            "#FFCE56"
          ]
        }]
    };
    this.dataTech = {
      labels: ['AngularJs', 'SQL','C#'],
      datasets: [
        {
          data: [300, 50, 100],
          backgroundColor: [
            "#FF6384",
            "#36A2EB",
            "#FFCE56"
          ],
          hoverBackgroundColor: [
            "#FF6384",
            "#36A2EB",
            "#FFCE56"
          ]
        }]
    };
    this.options = {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false
    };
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._service.getInternshipAssignments().subscribe(internships => {
      this.internships = internships;
      this.getSpecialisations();
      this.countSpecialisations();
    });
  }

  public getSpecialisations(): void {
    this.internships.forEach(i => {
      const helper: string [] = i.PreferredSpecialization.split(';');
      for(let h of helper) {
        if (this.specialisations.indexOf(h) === -1) {
          this.specialisations.push(h);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  public countSpecialisations(): void {
    let i: number = 0;
    for(i; i < this.specialisations.length; i++) {
      this.specialisationsArray[i] = 0;
    }
    this.internships.forEach(i => {
      switch (i.PreferredSpecialization) {
        case "AON":
          this.specialisationsArray[0]++;
          break;
        case "SWM":
          this.specialisationsArray[1]++;
          break;
        case "SNB":
          this.specialisationsArray[2]++;
          break;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Html:

```
<p-chart type="pie" class="charts col-sm-6" [data]="dataAfst" [options]="options"></p-chart>
```

Image of it showing nothing:

[image: Image of it showing nothing]

Comment: Could you show more of your code?

Comment: I edited my code a few seconds ago, the numbers acutally work but they only show up after some time. Ill put in the entire code so you can see it @JoeKeene

Comment: So the graph works but it takes time to load?

Comment: Try to move your graph data initialization inside `ngOnInit`, or `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: set your data `this.dataAfst` only after you received it from your service. You should add more code to this question, like component declaration and how the `specialisationsArray` is set.

Comment: putting it in the OnInit and in the AfterViewInit only makes it disappear @OmriLuzon

Comment: I guess you probably have more stuff going under the hood, try to simplify the problem because the examples in primeNG works, and they are really similar

Comment: Yes I use an observable in the OnInit method which takes some time. The examples in primeng have basic raw numbers @OmriLuzon